# how to increase the size of a div with a list based on the number of elements in the list

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

index.html

```
<div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

style.css

```
.list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 200px !important;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height : 115px;
}
```

in the above code the number of li items inside ul tag may vary so I want to keep the height for the div only that will be needed for the li tags to be displayed completely how to change the height dynamically based on the number of li elements and the space they occupy

Comment: don't specify any height, you are describing the default behavior

Answer (score 0):

Try adding max-height to the css of the class you are using.

```
    .list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 200px !important;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height : 115px;
    max-height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `max-height` from the `.list` and you will get the default CSS behavior - the more items you add, the more the height will grow by itself. Generally speaking, explicitly setting the `height` is unnecessary and sometimes harmful, the content is supposed to grow downwards and be vertically scrolled. There are instances when explicit height is needed, usually when dealing with images, for example when making a `carousel` you would want it to have specific `height` and even then it might be better to have a `max-height` (not to force the image to stretch).